# How can I change the VS Code problem count background so that the numbers are easier to read?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

The problems counts in the problems panel of my MacOS VS Code setup are dark text on a dark background, making the numbers hard to read. I am wondering what setting I can use to fix this.

Here's a screen grab:

[image: VS Code problems panel]

Here is my settings.json file (sorry, I couldn't get the indentation to work perfectly):

```json
{

    "workbench.colorTheme": "Quiet Light",
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    },
    "editor.guides.indentation": false,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "dart.flutterHotReloadOnSave": "all",
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": "on",
        "comments": "off",
        "strings": "on"
    },
    "java.imports.gradle.wrapper.checksums": [
        {
            "sha256": "e2b82129ab64751fd40437007bd2f7f2afb3c6e41a9198e628650b22d5824a14",
            "allowed": true
        }
    ],
    "dart.flutterCreateOrganization": "com.carlsmithswdev",
    "window.nativeTabs": true,
    "dart.showInspectorNotificationsForWidgetErrors": false,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "avdmanager.sdkPath": "/Users/carlsmith/Library/Android/sdk",
    "dart.debugExternalPackageLibraries": true,
    "dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "java.import.gradle.java.home": "/Users/carlsmith/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.12/Contents/Home",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `settings.json`:

```json
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
    "badge.background": "#ff0000",
    "badge.foreground": "#fff"
  }
}
```

Those badge colors do control other badges in vscode though, like SCM and breakpoints badges and search results counts so you'll have to find a good color for the various places badges can be.

Comment: if my theme is the red theme it will be hard to see

Comment: @rioV8 it's just an example? though I suppose Mark could add that you can wrap the customization in `"[theme-name]": { ... }` blocks.